# pyspark meandays calculation with respect to pandas code

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**#Pandas code**

```
temp = df_merge[['subscription_id', 'cancelleddate', 'subscriptionstartdate', 'termenddate']].drop_duplicates()
df_merge['mean_cancelled_sub_duration'] = (temp['cancelleddate']-temp['subscriptionstartdate']).dt.days.dropna().mean()/ 365
df_merge['mean_sub_duration'] = (temp['termenddate']-temp['subscriptionstartdate']).dt.days.dropna().mean()/365``
```

How to implement the same logic of the pandas code in pyspark, although I tried doing like this in pyspark but it didn't help me and we dropped rows and the calculation was wrong:

the columns with date in their name are of Datetype.

**#Failed Pyspark Conversion**

```
    temp = df_merge.select('subscription_id', 'cancelleddate', 'subscriptionstartdate', 'termenddate').dropDuplicates()
    temp = temp.withColumn("cancelled_sub_duration", datediff(temp.cancelleddate,temp.subscriptionstartdate)).withColumn("sub_duration", datediff(temp.termenddate,temp.subscriptionstartdate))
    temp = temp.na.drop(subset=['cancelled_sub_duration','sub_duration'])
    spec3 = Window.partitionBy("subscription_id")
    temp = temp.withColumn('mean_cancelled_sub_duration',(mean("cancelled_sub_duration").over(spec3))/365).withColumn('mean_sub_duration',(mean("sub_duration").over(spec3))/365)
    temp = temp.select(col('subscription_id').alias('subsid'), col('mean_cancelled_sub_duration'), col('mean_sub_duration'))
    df_merge = df_merge.join(broadcast(temp), df_merge.subscription_id==temp.subsid,"left").drop(col('subsid'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please post the expected output from the pandas code and what you are getting from the pyspark code so we can evaluate the differences between the data sets. Without that its hard to specifically see what is not working and what is.

In the mean time just looking specifically at the pandas code and trying to make a like for like in pyspark this is what I came up with.

```
temp = temp \
.withColumn('mean_cancelled_sub_duration' avg(datediff('cancelledate', 'subscriptionstartdate')).over(spec3) / lit(365)) \
.withColumn('mean_sub_duration', avg(datediff('termenddate', 'subscriptionstartdate')).over(spec3) / lit(365))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I have just created a function to smoothly convert a pandas dataframe to spark dataframe.

```
def equivalent_type(f):
 if f == 'datetime64[ns]': return DateType()
 elif f == 'int64': return LongType()
 elif f == 'int32': return IntegerType()
 elif f == 'uint8': return IntegerType()
 elif f == 'float64': return FloatType()
 else: return StringType()

def define_structure(string, format_type):
 try: typo = equivalent_type(format_type)
 except: typo = StringType()
 return StructField(string, typo)

def pandas_to_spark(pandas_df):
 columns = list(pandas_df.columns)
 types = list(pandas_df.dtypes)
 struct_list = []
 for column, typo in zip(columns, types):
   struct_list.append(define_structure(column, typo))
 p_schema = StructType(struct_list)
 return spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df, p_schema)
```

Then I converted the spark dataframes to pandas dataframe using toPandas() method

```
temp = df_merge.select('subscription_id', 'cancelleddate', 'subscriptionstartdate', 'termenddate').dropDuplicates()
temp = temp.toPandas()

temp['cancelleddate'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['cancelleddate'])
temp['subscriptionstartdate'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['subscriptionstartdate'])
temp['subscriptionstartdate'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['subscriptionstartdate'])

df_merge = df_merge.toPandas()
df_merge['mean_cancelled_sub_duration'] = (temp['cancelleddate']-temp['subscriptionstartdate']).dt.days.dropna().mean() / 365
df_merge['mean_sub_duration'] = (temp['termenddate']-temp['subscriptionstartdate']).dt.days.dropna().mean() / 365

df_merge = pandas_to_spark(df_merge)
```

I am using Spark 2.3.0 version so make I had to make sure that the date fields which I am converting to pandas dataframe should be in timestamp, otherwise this will throw an error.

This lastly fixed my issue and I got the mean (as this was not a kind of aggregated mean or row-wise mean, you can say it's a column mean.)